# What is the suitable linux version for Developers?

Tags: linux, linux-distributions

I am a novice application developer. I wanna to use Linux and try it out. But I've no idea of Linux distributions and what they are capable of. I've heard about Ubuntu, Linux mint, fedora.

But what is the best Linux distribution and what would you recommend for developer?

Comment: This question is considered Not Constructive as per the FAQ. For example: [What is the best linux distro for development of C/c++ programs?](http://superuser.com/questions/57127/what-is-the-best-linux-distro-for-development-of-c-c-programs?rq=1) which was closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd download [VMWare Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/), or [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), both of which are free, and then go to each of the distro's websites and grab their VM iso dowload and try it out. Nothing to lose doing it that way, as you'll soon see which you prefer. If they don't offer a VMX version for VMWare, you can simply use [easyVMX](http://www.easyvmx.com/) to roll your own from their regular downloads.

Ubuntu is always a good starting place, as it is designed to be user-friendly towards new linux users. There are also flavors of Ubuntu with different GUI's, such as [Kubuntu](http://www.kubuntu.org/) and [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/). But remember, underneath all the fluff, most Linux flavors are all the same and so your skills will transfer.

What do you develop? If you're doing web development and just need a LAMP stack, most Linux distros are simple to get up and running. As a Linux novice, I'd have you go with Ubuntu again, solely because of the amount of documentation and tutorials out there for you to learn from.

Comment: I do web development (ASP.NET) and also application (JAVA).

Comment: what do you think of Fedora?

Comment: I would advise you to start with Ubuntu, since it's more user friendly, and yes, there is http://askubuntu.com/ :)

Comment: +1'd. But I would mention VirtualBox as well. It's always nice to give a choice :)

Comment: Certainly, edited to include other options. VMWare is just my personal choice of course.

Comment: Choices are good but when OP's say beginner I try and guide a bit more and give less choices to help them get started.  There's plenty of time for other choices if they get into one.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are a developer, in my opinion you should consider to develop and test your software on popular distros.
Maybe the DistroWatch ranking could help you to decide.
Anyway Debian is a good distribution to develop software... you have also the opportunity to familiarize with .deb packages, a very popular format for all the major linux distributions (which are also Debian derivatives) like Ubuntu, Mint...